# Elasticsearch - type a query in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

the following query gets all documents in index "geoshapes" that have the location {32.0, 34.0}, how can I do the same in java?

```
GET /geoshapes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "coordinates": {
            "relation": "contains",
            "shape": {
              "coordinates": [
                32.0,
                34.0
              ],
              "type": "point"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import to your project a library that knows how to communicate with the ElasticSearch instance and do those queries programmatically (i.e. through your Java code). In other words, you need the Java client.

Have a look at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.13/index.html

Once you imported the library into your project, you can:

```java
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.common.geo.ShapeRelation;
import org.elasticsearch.common.geo.builders.CoordinatesBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.common.geo.builders.MultiPointBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.GeoShapeQueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder;

import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.geoShapeQuery;
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery;

BoolQueryBuilder query1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

GeoShapeQueryBuilder qb = geoShapeQuery(
        "location",
        new MultiPointBuilder(
                new CoordinatesBuilder()
                        .coordinate(32.0, 34.0)
                        .build()));

qb.relation(ShapeRelation.CONTAINS);

query1.filter(qb).must(matchAllQuery());

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("geoshapes");
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(query1);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Elastic has [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.13/java-rest-high.html) on the client that will be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have everything set (the client and the ES dependences), but I don't know how to set the settings for the QueryBuilder to achieve the same result I got with the provided query.

Comment: Got you. Which dependency exactly are you using? I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is it the `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` ?

Comment: I use elasticsearch and elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client dependencies, no version specified.

Comment: I would suggest you add the tag `java` to the question (also in the future). It is appropriate, and you get much more exposure.

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked!!! :D. I was having some hard time with the right dependencies, but now everything is fine and working perfectly. thank you again, you helped me a lot.